# Query to find sorted list of same columns with different conditions

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL, I have a question which I think you guys could help me out.

```
with properties as
(
  select count(*) as records
  From propdata P 
  where root_tstamp >= '2020-01-01' and and 
   (case when min_rooms is null and max_rooms is null then 0 else 1 end) = 1 and 
   (1 between min_rooms and max_rooms)
)
select apartments, count(*)/properties.records as all
From propdata P inner join properties 
on properties.records is not null
where root_tstamp >= '2020-01-01' and 
  (1 between rooms and rooms) and 
  (case when min_rooms is null and max_rooms is null then 0 else 1 end) = 1
group by apartments, all
order by all desc;
```

When I run this query I get the result as Apartments and all by sorting in descending order for the condition 1 rooms which is mentioned in where condition `((1 between min_rooms and max_rooms))`.

RESULT:

```
APARTMENTS             ALL

willington             9.893
greens apartment.      8.92
garden glow apartment. 6.82
```

What I need is column wise descending sorted list of apartments for each condition in terms of rooms 1, 2 ,3 in the where condition.

EXPECTED RESULT

```
APARTMENTS - 1ROOM         ALL.      APARTMENT - 2 ROOM    ALL

willington                9.893     FLOWARD APARTMENTS     8.1
greens apartment.         8.92.     KNIGHT ANGELS          5.8
garden glow apartment.    6.82.     HOVEY APARTMENTS.      2.3
```

Can anyone please help me out ! Thank you

I have mentioned the result which i get now and the result i wanted. is there any way to display the same column in terms of each condition sorted in descending to show seperate. Appreciate your help thank you.

Comment: Please add a sample of the table, so we can see the structure of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is not designed to work in that way.  It looks as through you need this for presentation to a human.  If so, do ***not*** try to do this in your data layer, do it in your application / presentation layer.

For a natural SQL structure, anything dynamically varying, such as the apartment's categorisation by number of rooms, should be in a column's values, not a new column.

```
SELECT
  rooms,
  apartments,
  COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()   AS all
FROM
  propdata
WHERE
      root_tstamp >= '2020-01-01' 
  AND (1 between rooms and rooms)
  AND (case when min_rooms is null and max_rooms is null then 0 else 1 end) = 1
GROUP BY
  rooms,
  apartments
ORDER BY
  rooms,
  all DESC;
```

Notes:

`SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()` totals up the `COUNT(*)` values from the whole result set, avoiding the need for your common table expression.

I'm not sure exactly what the `WHERE` clause is meant to be doing, so I've just copied it from your question.  If you explain it a bit more, with examples, that can most likely be improved / simplified too.

Comment: Hi MatBailie, Really appreciate your help. Just a quick question can I use union to show up all the columns which are seperated by each condition

Comment: @MuhammedNazeem `UNION` stacks datasets on top of each other, retaining the same numbers of columns.  The approach to get varying numbers of columns is called "dynamic SQL"; that is code that reads your data, works out how many columns are needed, and then ***the code*** writes a bespoke SQL query to generate those columns.  But, I can't stress this enough; It is one of the worst SQL Anti-Patterns in existence.  SQL is ***specifically*** and ***intentionally*** designed to have a static number of columns, not a dynamically varying number of columns.  Don't fight that, it's a false economy.

Comment: An analogy would be this; `While you CAN use a Hammer on a Screw, you really shouldn't`.  Use SQL the way it was designed and implemented, and reformat data in to different structures ***outside of the database***.

Comment: Now i got it. Thank you so much MatBailie, really appreciate your help and support. : )